# Error in lua-redis script

Tags: lua, redis

i'm trying to run the following lua script in redis:

```
for j=0,5000 do
    local i=redis.pcall('incr', 'SS:'..ARGV[2])%5000
    if redis.pcall('sismember', 'S:', i)==0 then
        if i > 4999 then
            redis.pcall('set', "SS:"..ARGV[2], 1)
            i = 1
        end
    end
        if redis.pcall('get', 'SS:'..ARGV[2])>4 then
            return 'forbiden'
        end
        redis.pcall('incr', 'C:'..ARGV[1])
        redis.pcall('sadd', 'US:'..ARGV[2], ARGV[1]..':'..i)
        redis.pcall('sadd', 'U:'..ARGV[1], ARGV[2]..':'..i)
        redis.pcall('sadd', 'S:'..ARGV[2], i)
        return i
    end
end
return false
```

but i am getting this error:

> Error compiling script (new function): user_script:20: '' expected near 'end'

i'm trying moving this end, tabulations, but i can't get it working, sorry if this is a dumb question, i'am really new at this lua thing!

Comment: you have an extra `end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working:

```
for j=0,5000 do
    local i=redis.pcall('incr', 'SS:'..ARGV[2])%5000
    if redis.pcall('sismember', 'S:', i)==0 then
        if i > 4999 then
            redis.pcall('set', "SS:"..ARGV[2], 1)
            i = 1
        end
    end
    if redis.pcall('get', 'SS:'..ARGV[2])>4 then
        return 'forbiden'
    end
    redis.pcall('incr', 'C:'..ARGV[1])
    redis.pcall('sadd', 'US:'..ARGV[2], ARGV[1]..':'..i)
    redis.pcall('sadd', 'U:'..ARGV[1], ARGV[2]..':'..i)
    redis.pcall('sadd', 'S:'..ARGV[2], i)
    return i
end
return false
```

As @karthikr said, you had an extra end at the very end.